# 'org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:'

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

We are getting the following error when trying to create a course entity instance on our web application. This is a JHipster app Full error log is below but the main error is

'org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:'

The offending code seems to be in this class: CourseResoure.java

The full code is at:

https://github.com/smitht06/aseproj

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: edu.uwf.cen6030.domain.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: edu.uwf.cen6030.domain.User
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:319)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy183.save(Unknown Source)
        at edu.uwf.cen6030.web.rest.CourseResource.createCourse(CourseResource.java:68)
```

updated code:

```
    @PostMapping("/courses")
    @Transactional()
    public ResponseEntity<Course> createCourse(@Valid @RequestBody Course course) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Course : {}", course);
        if (course.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new course cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        if (Objects.isNull(course.getTeacher())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid association value provided", ENTITY_NAME, "null");
        }

        Long userId = course.getTeacher().getId();
        userRepository.findById(userId).ifPresent(course::user);
        Course result = courseRepository.save(course);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/courses/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Comment: You're probably right about jhipster. It is quite complex. I added the notation you suggested and still got an error Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: edu.uwf.cen6030.domain.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: edu.uwf.cen6030.domain.User]

Comment: The annotation at method level was not required because it was already present at class level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you're loading a User entity from teacher id and then attach it to `user` field while it should be attached to teacher `ifPresent(course::teacher)` combined with `@Transactional` annotation at the class level `CourseResource` or at the method level `CourseResource#createCourse()`.

As a result, Hibernate complains that the teacher entity has not been loaded into `EntityManager` (i.e. teacher is detached) because it comes from JSON request body and contains only an id.

I must say that the code you attached cannot compile with the one from your git repository.

Following modified code passes `CourseResourceIT` unit tests

```java
    @PostMapping("/courses")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Course> createCourse(@Valid @RequestBody Course course) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Course : {}", course);
        if (course.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new course cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        if (Objects.isNull(course.getTeacher())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid association value provided", ENTITY_NAME, "null");
        }
        Long userId = course.getTeacher().getId();
        userRepository.findById(userId).ifPresent(course::teacher);
        Course result = courseRepository.save(course);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/courses/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
```

Comment: Great, the most important is that you understood the root cause because otherwise you'll get same issue with the students and chapters fields.